# Pandas efficient way to transpose to new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a spending dataset with 3 columns, date, id, and amount. The date column only changes by **month**. Example:

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['date','id','amount']
data = [['01-01-2019',1,320],
        ['01-01-2019',2,1000],
        ['01-01-2019',3,0],
        ['01-02-2019',1,0],
        ['01-02-2019',2,500],
        ['01-02-2019',3,123],
        ['01-03-2019',1,657],
        ['01-03-2019',2,300],
        ['01-03-2019',3,5],
        ['01-04-2019',1,3],
        ['01-04-2019',2,800],
        ['01-04-2019',3,42],
        ['01-05-2019',1,0],
        ['01-05-2019',2,656],
        ['01-05-2019',3,6]
        ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = cols
```

Looks like:

```
df.head()
         date  id  amount
0  01-01-2019   1     320
1  01-01-2019   2    1000
2  01-01-2019   3       0
3  01-02-2019   1       0
4  01-02-2019   2     500
```

I want to transpose this dataset so that each row is for one id, and the columns are the amounts spent per month. There can be a large number of months but its guaranteed that each month will have all users in them. Example:

**Ideal outcome**

```
   id  month 1  month 2  month 3  month 4  month 5
0   1      320        0      657        3        0
1   2     1000      500      300      800      656
2   3        0      123        5       42        6
```

I have a rather inefficient way to do this now, and am sure theres a more panda-esque way to do this. probably using groupby or something but I cant figure out how. Would anyone have any idea?

**Current method**

```
ids = df['id'].unique()
for uniq_id in ids:
    sub_amt = df[df['id'] == uniq_id]['amount'].to_list()
    temp = [uniq_id] + sub_amt
    master.append(temp)

transposed_df = pd.DataFrame(master)
transposed_df.columns= ['id'] + ['month {}'.format(x) for x in range(1,len(sub_amt)+1)]
```

Thank you!

**-- EDIT --**

I know the question got marked as duplicate, but to save you a click and trouble of fitting those examples to this specific question, I solved this question by using `df.pivot(index='id', columns='date',values ='amount')`

Comment: Maybe with pivot?

Comment: How though? I still cant figure it out after reading the post

Comment: Like this! df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%d-%m-%Y')
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
df_f = pd.pivot_table(df,values='amount',index='id',columns='month',aggfunc=np.sum)

If you open a new question, let me know and I'll paste it as an answer with the expected output.

Comment: Thanks for that! i just figured it out: `df.pivot(index='id', columns='date',values ='amount')` but yours works too!

Comment: Don't forget the agg function! I find pivot_table a bit more flexible, but of course your function also gets the job done :)

Comment: pd.pivot(df.groupby([df["date"].str.extract(r"-(\d{2})-")[0],"id"]).sum().reset_index(), index="id", columns=0, values="amount")

Comment: Wait why would I need the aggregate function? I get the same results @IvanLibedinsky

Comment: Perhaps I mistankly supposed it is a requiered arguments, seems not to be the case for `pivot`. Also, the default operation for `pivot` seems to be sum.